# split and join with jQuery each to add space after comma

Tags: jquery, split, each

trying to take this content:

```
<div class="content">one,two,three</div>
<div class="content">four,five,six</div>
<div class="content">seven,eight,nine</div>
```

and .split and .join using jQuery's each.

```
$('.content').each(function() {
    var mydata = $(this).text().split(',').join(", ");
    $(this).text(mydata);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXgx2

Comment: ok i think this does work. I had an error in my code. but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course you can use `split` and `join`:

```
$(".content").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.split(",").join(", ");
});
```

But I'd recommend to use regular expression instead:

```
$(".content").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZXgx2/6/

Comment: on another post I read that split-join is faster than regex. true?

Comment: regex seems like overkill for a character replace.

Comment: @nathanbweb For short strings split and join might be faster, but not for long strings. Arrays need more memory.

Answer (score 2):

you solution is fine, your fiddle is wrong : `split(', ')`

Answer (score 1):

No reason to split, join, or call `.each`. Just modify the text of all `.content` elements via a quick regex:

```
​$(".content").text(function(i,v){
    return v.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/uAHBU/

Comment: @nathanbweb I did, and I still don't think splitting and joining is wise. It's unnecessary preoptimization at best. There's no reason to create an array only to dissolve it immediately here.